# Exec() command in Linux does not perform any action from a PHP page

Tags: php, linux, exec, festival

I'm trying to run the following command from a PHP file in a web browser:

```
 exec('festival --tts /var/www/test.txt &');
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.  I thought of trying 'echo' but there is nothing to return to see if the command is working.  I set permissions for test.txt to 777.  I also ran the command in a shell and it works just fine - just not when submitted by a PHP script.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't doing anything? You can probably also check process exit value -- that's `$?`, at least in Ruby and Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Provide the full path to the `festival` binary, you can find it out on the console with `which festival` command, then use it in your exec call, like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/festival --tts /var/www/test.txt &');
```

**Update:**
You need to make sure the folder where you are creating the file has write permission for the user running php which usually is `www-data` on debian based distros.

Comment: I ran "which festival" and found it in "/usr/bin/festival".  Unfortunately, when I add this to the PHP file, it still does not run the command.  Is there a permissions error here somewhere?  If so, what do I do to change it?

Comment: Then it's probably a permission problem, what is the ouput of this command?  "ls -ld /var/www"       Also, which linux distro are you running this?

Comment: That is the problem, the path to file needs to be inside a folder that is owned by the user tha runs PHP (usually www-data in debian/ubuntu distros).

Comment: Change /var/www/test.txt for a path that is inside your DOCUMENT_ROOT and it will be ok, if you want it outside DOCUMENT_ROOT make sure you change the permission of the folder to be owned by www-data user.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you aren't returning the input. The syntax for this is:

```
exec('command', $output);
```

where $output is the variable in which the script's output will be stored. Oddly, this output will be returned as an array, so don't forget to `implode()` it when you're done if you're expecting a string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  There is no output from this command, only audio.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `festival` program print any output? If so, try capturing that. Also check the return value.

```
exec('/usr/bin/festival --tts /var/www/test.txt &', $output, $return);
```

Dump the output array, like so:

```
var_dump($output);
```

Any non-zero return value usually indicates an error:

```
echo $return;
```

Comment: No, the "festival" command is a text-to-speech command.  There is only audio as an output.  However, I tried what you wrote, and this is what was returned:   array(0) { } 0